# Does proxypass put a toll on network traffic for streamable sources?

Tags: nginx, amazon-web-services, proxypass

First of all I have never tried it and it may not be possible, but I do imagine a case when things like AWS S3 services offers files on their "buckets", and some part of security procedure is to tamper the real URL.

Many systems do this by passing the response through their backend, like they convert:

s3.bucket.example-com-44512.aws.eu/image/file/0x123abc

into

example.com/file/123

I see a problem in how people are fetching the content from AWS just to process it on their own servers and return it back, there is little to none savings on network traffic.

What I try to do is to use a proxypass to tamper the url, ie. files.example.com into s3.bucket.example-com-44512.aws.eu, and I think it works just fine, but I never tried it for streaming resources, like long MP4 video files.

Wondering if somebody could confirm that it could work

Comment: and what is the business related question in here?

Comment: The question isn't clear, I'm not sure what you're trying to say / work out. URL rewriting is generally ok.